# Python Tableau Server Client to refresh Cache memory in Tableau Server

Tags: python, tableau-api

My org had a dashboard some time ago that was very complex and took some time to load, however, once we loaded it once, performance was fine for the rest of the day (due to cache memory being refreshed). Therefore, we had someone in our team go open the dashboard everyday early in the morning so the cache memory for the day was refreshed. I am now learning about Tableau Server Client (TSC) module in python, which uses the Tableau API to manipulate Tableau server, and I am wondering if I could accomplish the same thing using TSC. Is that possible? If so, what would be the syntax? I looked into the [documentation](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/) and I didn't see anything about it. I am currently able to trigger an extract refresh using TSC, but I would like to see if I can just refresh the cache memory of a dashboard. Or perhaps there is another function of TSC that does something similar. Any thoughts?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do what is called cache warming for Tableau Server 9.0+ using subscriptions.

Here are the steps found in the tableau [kb](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/warming-the-tableau-server-cache-using-subscriptions):

Starting with Tableau Server 9.0, the Cache Server can be "warmed" with data using the Subscription function. Triggering a subscription email that includes a thumbnail after executing an extract refresh will cause the queries to run for the viz and load into the external query cache.

If a user wants a fast-loading view for an 8 AM meeting:

1. Tableau Administrator schedules an extract refresh at 2 AM.
2. Tableau Administrator schedules a subscription email at 5 AM.
3. User loads workbook quickly from stored cache at 8 AM.

**Note**: if "Refresh More Often" is selected in the Data Connections tab of Configure Tableau Server, the cache will be cleared every time the view is loaded. Additionally, regardless of cache settings, if a user hits the "Refresh Data" button on the toolbar, the Tableau Server will fetch new data.

If you want to use python then I would just use `requests.get()` to hit your url on a scehdule.